# Module missing in Android Studio and Gradle sync fails

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have set up a brand new project in Android Studio 1.1 RC 1:

- Created an Android project [app] (because there is no way to create an App Engine backend project right away).
- Added an existing backend module by first creating a new App Engine module and then manually importing the files [backend].
- Removed the Android app module [app].
- Added a Java library module, same procedure, first creating a new module, then importing files [common].

Everything compiles fine, but Android Studio has two problems:

1. When I look at Project Structure, the [common] module is missing in the left pane, but it still appears as referenced module in the right pane!?

[image: Project Structure]

2. My Project tree looks fine and all modules are recognized, but gradle is telling me the sync failed.

[image: Project Tree]

Gradle says "Task '' not found in root project" ('' is empty string as it seems). I get a Warning and an exception in the log when running from Terminal, but it doesn't seem to be related (related to Indexing), so I haven't included it here.

settings.gradle has both modules specified:

```
include ':backend', ':common'
```

I tried to exchange the .iml file of the main project with a fake one which contains both modules, with the result that (besides multiple side effects) both modules were there. (I restored the original state because of the side-effects.)

Here are my gradle files:

Root module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

[backend]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.17'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.4'
    compile project(':common')
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

[common]

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'cc.closeup'
version = 'v2-2.0-SNAPSHOT'

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.artifactId = 'common'
        pom.packaging = 'jar'
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Anything else that you'd like to see here?

Comment: If you want to build an AE project only. You could try this tutorial for intellij idea https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-google-app-engine-project.html

Comment: [@JessonAtherton if you want your kudos, post this as an answer. It's better than my suggested workaround.]

Comment: Done, I hope your all good to go with AE now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build an AE project only. You could try this tutorial for intellij idea jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-google-app-engine-project.html

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I removed [app]. It seems that if you create an App Engine backend module, you must keep a "fake" frontend module in the same project to keep Android Studio/gradle happy.

In earlier Android Studio versions it was possible to remove the frontend module without problems, but it seems Google has locked this somehow. It still works when I keep the fake frontend module.

--

Why I configured it this way? In my configuration, I have backend and frontend modules in different projects, and I have the backend project install libraries into local Maven, which I then pick up within my frontend project (with a team you would choose a local Maven server). This configuration has multiple advantages, for example that I can test backend/frontend on two screens simultaneously without switching back and forth all the time. Some companies may also want this configuration to keep their backend code separate and secure.